# Scipy: Display xlabel propably

Tags: matplotlib, plot, scipy, label

I'm quite new to SciPy. For university I've to evaluate and plot the link between tension and stretching over time. My plot seems to be correct but i want the axis to look nice.
Is there an easy solution to display the mm^2 in a nice way?

```
import pylab
pylab.rc('font',size=8)
pylab.rc('lines',linewidth=3)
fig=pylab.figure()
P=fig.add_subplot(111)
P.plot(t,s,color='red',linestyle='-')
P.set_xlabel('Zeit $t$ [s]', fontsize=12)
P.set_ylabel('Spannung'  r'$\sigma$' r'$[\frac{N}{mm**2}]$')
P.grid(True)
fig.autofmt_xdate()
fig.savefig('odeSnPb1.png')
fig.clf()
```

Thanks alot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [mathtext](http://matplotlib.org/users/mathtext.html) provided by matplotlib:

```
import pylab
pylab.rc('font',size=8)
pylab.rc('lines',linewidth=3)
fig=pylab.figure()
P=fig.add_subplot(111)
P.plot(t,s,color='red',linestyle='-')
P.set_xlabel('Zeit $t$ [s]', fontsize=12)
P.set_ylabel('Spannung'  r'$\sigma$' r'$[\frac{\rm{N}}{\rm{mm}^2}]$')
P.grid(True)
fig.autofmt_xdate()
fig.savefig('odeSnPb1.png')
fig.clf()
```

Alternatively, you could [render your labels using LaTeX](http://matplotlib.org/users/usetex.html#usetex-tutorial).

Comment: Thanks alot. Worked out just fine!

Comment: It would be nice, if you could accept the answer that solved your problem or helped you most.

Answer (score 0):

Try `r'$[\frac{N}{mm^2}]$'` The ^ is the TeX character for exponents

Comment: Units would still appear italic in this case.

Comment: Then the question is what one considers "nice" ;)

Comment: Fair enough :) Generally, units are set in upright font, though.

Answer (score 0):

Define 'nice'.
If what you want is a normally looking units, then try `r'$\sigma\,\mathrm{mm}^2$'` or `r'$\sigma\,$mm$^2$'`